# Org-mode tables exported as latex arrays within eqnarray environment, how?

Tags: org-export, latex, org-table

If I have constructed a blocked array using an org-mode table, I can easily export the table as, e.g., a pmatrix array as presented below. However, the pmatrix is exported within a math environment (\[..\]). How can I change that to, e.g., an eqnarray environment in order to attach an equation reference?

So, I have this code:

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment pmatrix :mode math :math-prefix N= :math-suffix ,
| A   | B |
| B^T | D |
```

which is exported to

```
\[
N=\begin{pmatrix}
 A & B \\
 B^T & D \\
\end{pmatrix},
\]
```

I wish to replace the \[..\] by eqnarray, i.e., produce

```
\begin{eqnarray}
N=\begin{pmatrix}
 A & B \\
 B^T & D \\
\end{pmatrix},\label{eq:normal}
\end{eqnarray}
```

Is this possible using org-mode options or do I have to re-write the back-end? If so, where in the back-end should I start?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a work-around in the following:

```
\refstepcounter{equation}
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment pmatrix :mode math :math-prefix N= :math-suffix ,\tag{\theequation}\label{eq:blocks}
| A   | B |
| B^T | D |
```

It is however a kludge and gives a different vertical spacing as around an `eqnarray`. Another version that moves all reference stuff into the `#+ATTR_LATEX` block is

```
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment pmatrix :mode math :math-prefix \refstepcounter{equation}N= :math-suffix ,\tag{\theequation}\label{eq:blocks}
| A   | B |
| B^T | D |
```

However, it does not solve the original problem.